# Using image-url within sass to avoid hard coding image assets path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I've just started to work with the rails asset pipeline, I'm a front-end guy. 
I'm trying to use image-url helper within sass files so that I don't have to hard-code the path.

The following **SASS**

```
.some-class
  background: image-url("image.png")
```

generates the following **CSS**

```
.some-class{
  background: url("asset/image.png");
}
```

How do I use the image-url helper to generate the following css, without hard-coding the image path ?

```
.some-class{
  background: url("asset/image.png") no-repeat 0 0 #fff;
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something here?  The solution looks obvious:  `background: image-url("image.png") no-repeat 0 0 #fff;`

Comment: I had tried this one also, not working for me..giving some kind of error..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
.some-class
  background-image: image-url("image.png")
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
```

and so on.

or

```
 background: #fff image-url("image.png") no-repeat 0 0;
```

should work.

Answer (score -1):

You propably should use:

```
background-image: asset-url("image.png", image) no-repeat 0 0 #fff;
```

The asset-url is a sass/rails feature, which lets the asset pipeline do some (production) work for you. You can read about that feature [here](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#features).

Using the helper is preferable over a plain `url("image.png")`, as it gives you finger printed URLs in production. See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947967/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-why-should-i-use-the-asset-helpers-in-a-scss-file?rq=1).

Comment: It should work, what is the excat error? Maybe replace `asset-url("image.png", image)` with `image-url('image.png')`.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the following StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304607/sass-rails-helpers-image-url-asset-url-are-not-working-in-rails-3-2-1?rq=1
It gives some additional pointers (esp. is your file included in the asset precompile list?)