# Get fingerprint to work with sass.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-finger-printing

I'm deploying my application and I'm having trouble with the images in my `application.css.sass` file. When I visit my page, the css links to something like `icon-login.png` but thanks to the fingerprint from precompile the actual filename is `icon-login-f0a51964c9ccbe966746b66d7f2ad310.png`.

When I check images that are placed in the erb code (so not from a stylesheet) they refer to the right images with the fingerprint.

What's the best way to fix this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline - Why should I use the Asset Helpers in a SCSS file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947967/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-why-should-i-use-the-asset-helpers-in-a-scss-file)

Comment: Well, found the answer. Ofcourse after posting. It's changing `background: url('icon-#{$icon}.png') $blue no-repeat 7px 7px` to `background: image-url('icon-#{$icon}.png') $blue no-repeat 7px 7px` adding the image to the url worked.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't use

```
background url(filename.jpg)
```

You need,

```
background image-url('filename.jpg')
```

also notice the extra dashes around the `filename.jpg`

Comment: You mean single quotes?

Comment: There's an edit function if you want to edit/improve or change answers.